# Why does splitting one class into two improve testability?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am reading a book 'Functional Programming In Scala' by Paul Chiusana.

It gives an example of impure function as:

```
class Cafe {
  def buyCoffee(cc: CreditCard): Coffee = {
    val cup = new Coffee()
    cc.charge(cup.price)
    cup
  }
}
```

Author argues that cc.charge() call has side effects,hence the code is difficult to test.

Then a better approach is suggested as:

```
class Cafe {
   def buyCoffee(cc: CreditCard, p: Payments): Coffee = {
    val cup = new Coffee()
    p.charge(cc, cup.price)
    cup
   }
}
```

Author argues:"Though side effects still occur when we call p.charge(cc, cup.price), we have at
least regained some testability. Payments can be an interface, and we can write a mock
implementation of this interface that is suitable for testing."

But we can have a similar interface based approach for first implementation too. Then how is second approach a better one?

Comment: Don't look too much into this example. You have a point, but even conceding that, the authors still say there's something better.

Comment: I see you also asked this question on users.scala-lang.org. If you're going to ask the same question in two different places on the Internet, it's polite to include links back and forth so that someone doesn't waste time in one place repeating information that you already got in the other place.

Comment: users.scala-lang.org post is https://users.scala-lang.org/t/impure-functions/2242

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you gain is just granularity. It's easier to write mocks for only the things that need to be mocked if roles are cleanly separated - if the `CreditCard` type both represents credit card information *and* performs charges, then you have to mock half of its responsibilities, which seems a bit awkward. In contrast, when you separate the types, `CreditCard` can just be a dumb case class, and `Payments` can be something you mock in its entirety.